# Have to kill a bash script twice for it to run

Tags: bash, loops

If I run this script for several files, it works fine...

```sh
files=(./pics/all/*.jpg) # create array from directory
total=${#files[@]} # array length
i=0
for file in ${files[@]}; do
    filename="${file##*/}" # turns ./pics/all/045315.jpg into 045315.jpg
    convert $file -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -quality 1 -interlace JPEG -colorspace RGB ./pics/all_resampled/$filename;
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
    progress=$(echo "scale=2;$i/$total*100" | bc)
    echo $i/$total ${progress%.*}% $file RESAMPLED;
done
```

However, for the 30,000+ images I have, if I run the script, it does nothing.

When I kill it with `CTRL` + `c`, it prints the whole array.

Killing it again it prints the array again, and only after that does it start looping and resampling...

What is going on?

Comment: I don't see any reason it'd do that. Try adding the `set -x` command at the beginning to get an execution trace, and see where it's hanging and what command is making it print the array.

Comment: Expanding a glob with 30,000 files and copying it to an array will take some time. I think you are interrupting while this is happening. The array is unnecessary, just loop through the glob. Also, don't fork out to `bc(1)` 30,000 times, use built in arithmetic: `$((100*i/total))`.

Comment: @dan Can you please provide the full code as an answer?

Comment: @Ivan : The only potential problem I see is the missing quotes in the `for` line. Aside from this, why do you think it isn't doing anything - maybe you are not patient enough. How long did you wait? Still, even such a huge array should be populate in a couple of seconds. Could it be by chance that some of the `jpg` entries are symlinks pointing to some slow network share? I would - after setting `total` - insert a `echo Start converting $total files`, to get some idea of what's happening.

Comment: BTW, the fact that it prints the array after the first control-C suggests that it hangs inside the `convert` of the first file.

Comment: @user1934428 it suggests the opposite to me, as the array contents shouldn't be printed at all.

Comment: Right, there is nothing in the code posted which would print the array. My idea was that if the problem was really during populating the array, the Control-C would have simply killed the script and nothing would be printed. Perhaps `convert` is printing weird stuff when interrupted?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, the problem was two images in the beginning having the names of `*.jpg` and `**.jpg`. When I removed those images, it worked fine. I did implement your suggestions to make the code better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I had two images named `*.jpg` and `**.jpg` which caused all the weirdness.

This caused the first two resamples to be done as if the whole directory was a single file.

Revised code:

```sh
fileCount=$(ls ./pics/all | wc -l)
i=0
for file in ./pics/all/*.jpg; do
    filename="${file##*/}" # turns ./pics/all/045315.jpg into 045315.jpg
    convert $file -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -quality 1 -interlace JPEG -colorspace RGB ./pics/all_resampled/$filename;
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
    progress=$((100 * i / fileCount))
    echo $i/$fileCount $progress% $file RESAMPLED;
done
```

Comment: In the original code, `"${files[@]}"` needs to be quoted. This would stop `*.jpg` expanding in the loop. You would have seen it straight away. If you want to handle thousands of files, consider `find . -exec convert .. {} \;`. This avoids having to expand the file list on the command line first.

Comment: If you really want to count the files first, use `find ./pics/all -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec printf %c {} + | wc -c`. `ls` is not reliable.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions @dan, I've learned a lot from you.